# Stereotypical, recognisable, educated version of "gosh"

Tags: expressions

Is there an expression like "*gosh*" that a stereotypical upper-class British character would say for expressing surprise?

I've thought of "*parbleu*", but it being a loan word from French, it doesn't sound right as a stereotypical English expression.

I would avoid "*My Lord*" because of possible moral implications with the reader.

Note: it should be easily recognisable by a non-English audience.

Is there such an expression? Thanks!

Comment: The [OED](http://www.oed.com/) lists many synonyms for “gosh” in their Historical Thesaurus. In order to know which ones to list, can you please answer the following: Does the word you want have to be a strictly British word, and can the word be informal?

Comment: not necessarily "strictly" British, but it should be used also by the British; it can be informal but should anyway denote an upper-class person (think of a member of the nobility talking with his/her peers in a informal context, behind closed doors)

Comment: "Dear me"/"oh me" from the Historical Thesaurus sound good to me!

Comment: You were able to get access?

Comment: Gosh (!) I hope I looked in the right place: http://www.oed.com/view/th/class/128862

Comment: Are you a subscriber or did you use your library card?

Comment: I am actually sitting in a library in England right now, so well, I guess it explains why I have access! I had not considered that the service would normally require access!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately unless you have the physical books, the OED requires either a paid subscription or your library to provide you access. I have access via the NYPL, or the New York Public Library.

Comment: And I would look [here](http://www.oed.com/view/th/class/128473) instead as it is in the category of surprise. You did say, “Is there an expression like ‘gosh’ that a stereotypical upper-class British character would say for **expressing surprise**?”

Answer (score 2):

I think “[I say](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/i_say)” is the term for you. This is my reasoning: Oxford considers “I say” to be both a British form of exclamation as well as a “dated” one (I prefer to call it quaint). The upper-classes were very likely to use wonderfully old-fashioned language in keeping with tradition. Thus, the older the word, the more likely the upper-classes used it.

Answer (score -1):

You could try one of these:

[I say!](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/I_say)
[Zounds!](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zounds)*
[Strewth!](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strewth)*
[Blimey!](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blimey#English)*

*These words do contain an indirect reference to the Deity, which you may want to avoid for your purposes.

Comment: I like Blimey! The connection to the Deity is hidden by the strong alteration of the original phrase, and to me it sounds like it's the most recognisable of the four

Comment: All these are at the very least dated (***Zounds!*** is positively *archaic*). And I'd say ***Blimey**!* is extremely lower-class, whereas OP asked for a stereotypically *upper-class* usage (in which context ***Gosh**!* is still relatively current, and I honestly doubt many speakers would be consciously aware of its "religious" etymology).

Comment: Strewth is also lower class. 
'I say!' is a classic for anyone who has watched films and TV involving British upper class characters.

Comment: "By Jove!" is another upper-class, but dated, possibility (referring to the Roman god to avoid blasphemy).

Comment: Oxford considers “[blimey](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blimey)” and “[strewth](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/strewth)” to be informal. It is unlikely that those belonging to the upper-classes would have used such colloquial terms, preferring instead elevated or formal language.